# typemock with linq functions inside fake with Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, typemock

If I have a typemock test that fakes an instance where the members must specify return values such as below:

```
WallLayers layers = Isolate.Fake.Instance<WallLayers>(Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues);
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => layers.GetCoreProfile()).CallOriginal();
```

If within the original GetCoreProfile method I have a linq query

```
wallPoints = fe.GetFacePointsConstrainedBy<Int32>(FaceExtractor.BottomFace, constraints, selector1)
               .Where(p => p.Z == wallReferenceLevel)
```

when running the test the following exception is thrown

```
TypeMock.TypeMockException: 
*** Unexpected Call to AU.Com.Monarch.Model.Revit.WallLayers.<GetCoreProfile()
   at dm.b(Object A_0, String A_1, String A_2, MethodBase A_3, Object[] A_4, Object A_5)
   at Typemock.Interceptors.Profiler.InternalMockManager.getReturn(Object that, String typeName, String methodName, Object methodParameters, Boolean isInjected, Boolean isInterceptedType, Object p1)
   at AU.Com.Monarch.Model.Revit.WallLayers.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<GetCoreProfile>b__8(Point3D`1 p) in C:\revitMBS\source\ExternalFrame\ExternalFrame\Monarch\Model\Revit\WallLayers.cs:line 278
```

1. Is there a way I can get Typemock to CallOriginal on the linq functions as well,
2. or is there a  way I can get these functions ignored in the context of Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues
3. or is my only option to remove the Members.MustSpecifyReturnValues in this situation?

Thanks for your input in advance.